# How to match array number elements with Gridview cell values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I have a GridView1 with numbers in it and I want to match those numbers with an array of numbers, when it matches should fire the message:

I tried this code:

```
    int[] matchN = new int[100];

foreach (KeyValuePair<double, int> OneRank in MyRank)
{
    for (int kw = 1; kw < matchN.Length; ++kw)
                   
     {

    
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value].Cells[2].Text)== matchN[kw])
                        {
    //everytime it matches it should fire
                            TextBox2.Text += "Number 5 is in Column2"
    
 

               }
       }
 

   

    }
```

I want all 100 numbers to check matching and when match the message should fire but it does not check even one element...

Comment: Is your sample missing some code?  `new int[100]` will create an array of *size* 100, but the contents of it will be filled with 0's.  So your code is only checking for each grid cell to match 0

Comment: if I use this method int[] matchN = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToArray(); it takes out matched cells but the problem is that it does not takes out ordered by matchN,,, so in  other words I want matchN to dictate the matching and not the GridView....

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have 4 rows in `GridView1`. The following code shows how the rows are accessed:

```
GridView1.Rows[0] // getting the 1st row
GridView1.Rows[1] // getting the 2nd row
GridView1.Rows[2] // getting the 3rd row
GridView1.Rows[3] // getting the 4th row
```

You are accessing the rows with `OneRank.Value`.

```
GridView1.Rows[OneRank.Value]
```

`OneRank.Value` is a value of a Dictionary. How do you define your dictionary? Accessing the GridView1 rows with `OneRank.Value` has the potential of out of range.